# How can you run the Ruby debugger simultaneously with Autotest?

Tags: ruby, debugging, rspec

I use `bundle exec autotest` to run my test specs as I work however I'd also like to be able to drop in and out of the debugger.

I can't figure out how to get autotest running and also listen for debug commands though. Every time it goes through a debugger statement it prints:

```
***** debugger statement ignored, use -d or --debug option to enable debugging
```

I've tried calling autotest with both of those options i.e.

```
bundle exec autotest --debugger
# => just ignores the debugger

bundle exec autotest -d
# => complains that -d is an invalid option

bundle exec autotest --debug
# => still doesn't trigger but advises 
#    "debugger statement ignored, use -d or --debug option to enable debugging"
```

How can I call the debugger while using autotest?

At the moment I always have to drop back to manually calling `rspec spec -d`

(My setup is Rails 3)

Comment: have you tried bundle exec autotest --debug? w/o the extra 'ger' at the end?

Comment: I hadn't before (now edited) but on trying it it doesn't work either

Comment: nice of them to tell you --debug doesn't work, try using --debug. hair pulling out time :P

Comment: It's an `invalid option` unfortunately :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following to your .rspec file in the root of your project:

```
--debug
```

When autotest runs, it will execute rspec using the config file, and will jump into the debug console whenever any debugger statements are executed.